# Changing systemd HandleLidSwitch setting during run-time?

Tags: systemd, laptop, acpi, logind

The setting `HandleLidSwitch` is defined in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` as follows:

`HandleLidSwitch=<hibernate,ignore,...>`

The setting is applied successfully on boot. However, I would like to change the setting during run-time depending on the AC state:

If my laptop is charging, use `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`. If my laptop is on battery, use  `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`.

Is this somehow possible to realise with current systemd?

Answer (score 5):

logind provides an [inhibitor lock](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) mechanism that allows user software to override system policy. It allows, for example, Gnome to take control of all ACPI buttons and switches for as long as it is active. You could use it to inhibit "handle-lid-switch" when the device is plugged in, and drop the lock when it is unplugged.

The best approach would be to write a script in a language with DBus bindings and use logind's `Inhibit()` method, but systemd does provide a `systemd-inhibit` command that can be used from a shell script. Note that it is intended to be used as a wrapper, holding the lock until the child process exits:

```
systemd-inhibit --what=handle-lid-switch SOME_COMMAND_HERE
```

P.S. This all assumes you are not using a desktop environment that is already blocking "handle-lid-switch". Running `systemd-inhibit` without arguments will list existing inhibitors.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I run only Openbox window manager instead of a full DE. If I understood you correctly, it should be for instance `# systemd-inhibit --what=handle-lid-switch suspend`? I get this error: `Failed to execute suspend: No such file or directory`. Furthermore, `# systemd-inhibit` gives me `0 inhibitors listed.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The function is inhibited as long as `SOME_COMMAND_HERE` is running. For instance you could run `systemd-inhibit --what=handle-lid-switch sleep 20` to block the configured action for a closed lid for 20 seconds. In your specific use case you would need to implement a command which starts as soon as AC is connected and is terminated if not.